# how to get location during app launch

Tags: android, location, fragment, sharedpreferences

In my app, I want to get current location during app launch. In my Main Activity(first activity), first I get location (latitude and longitude) and save Shared Preferences. After that, I place HomeFragment. I want to see HomeFragment when app open. 
In my HomeFragment I want to get sharedPrefreferences than use location and latitude information to compute distance. 
However, this didn't work, when I start the app, It place HomeFragment before save SharePreferences.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation(this);
            myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tx.replace(R.id.flContent, new HomeFragment());
            tx.commit();

        public MyLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new MyLocation.LocationResult() {

            @Override
            public void gotLocation(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                double Longitude = location.getLongitude();
                double Latitude = location.getLatitude();

                try {
                    System.out.println("lat"+Latitude);
                    System.out.println("long"+Longitude);
                    SharedPreferences locationpref = getApplication()
                            .getSharedPreferences("location", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = locationpref.edit();  prefsEditor.commit();
                    prefsEditor.putString("Longitude", Longitude + "");
                    prefsEditor.putString("Latitude", Latitude + "");


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

    }
```

HomeFragment :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), restaurantList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("restaurantId", String.valueOf(restaurantList.get(position).getId()));
                MenuLineItemFragment fragment2 = new MenuLineItemFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment2);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });


        SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getApplication().getSharedPreferences("location", MODE_PRIVATE);
        latitude = pref.getString("Latitude","");
        longitude = pref.getString("Longitude","");

        if(i==1){
            request(); //I use longitude and latitude information in this method.
            i++;
        }



        return rootView;

    }
```

In my Manifest file, I give permissions.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

How can I get current location during start app? Also, what should I do if user's location is off?

Answer (score 0):

Some of `Location` class methods is done in background such as `getLongitude` and `getLatitude`, so doesn't matter which line of code `Fragment` initialization or `getLocation` because getLocation takes time.

In your code :-

You call `getLocation` > GPS running in background to get location > `Fragment` get initialized > `getLocation` finishes in `background` and pass the returned values to `foreground` > `gotLocation` is called.

Solutions :-

**First way** is initialize the `fragment` after `gotLocation` and this is not recommended at all.

**Second way** save values in `sharedPrefreferences` and update your UI(fragment) when the `gotLocation` finishes (Could use progress bar and hide it after gotLocati`enter code here`on called).

Comment: ,thank you for your response. I understand now. How can I ensure that gotLocation finish? and than I can place my fragment. @Mohamed Embaby

Comment: make a Runnable in MainActivity with postDelayed 2000ms or value you want, and check hasAltitudevalue inside the Runnable if true place your fragment if false call Runnable again and make counter, you don't want Runnable to be called in infinite loop.... for more efficient check first if GPS is turned on and there is Internet Access.